# the characteristic subgroups of a finite group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $N \leq G'$ such that $N$ has a prime order, $p$. Can we say that $N char G'$? (characteristic subgroup).

Comment: No, $N$ need not even be normal.

Comment: why this is not characteristic?

Comment: Have you tried some examples? Like for example $A_5$.

Comment: ok thanks for response, if G is not equal G', is it true?

Comment: No, try $S_5$..

Comment: ok thanks, so N is not normal in G, ok?

Comment: It is also possible that $N$ is normal in $G$  but not characteristic: take a subgroup of order $3$ in one of the direct factors of $S_3 \times S_3$.

Comment: in general case, can we say N is normal in G?

Comment: No, of course not. You just had an example where it was not.

Comment: Is there counter example of solvable group dear Tobias Kildetoft ?

Comment: Yes, there are even counter examples in $p$-groups, though if $p$ is the smallest prime dividing the order and the subgroup is normal then it will be characteristic (this is unrelated to being contained in the derived subgroup).

Comment: i dont understand your comment, you said in your comment, in the p-groups is normal but i want a counter example, that is a solvable group which N in nonnormal in G

Comment: And I said that there were examples of $p$-groups where this is the case.

Comment: Sorry, so if G is solvable in assumption, then N is not normal in G, ok?

Comment: I am no longer sure what you are asking, but pretty much any permutation of the conditions involved will have both examples where the answer is yes and where it is no.

Comment: Im so sorry to disturbing you!